# AlertDialog with different background color?

Tags: android, background, dialog

I have a problem with my AlertDialogs. If the language of the app is German the AlertDialogs are black. If the language is English (Standard) the AlertDialogs are white. How could this happen? I did not set a custom Theme.

This is how I create an AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create 2 different Layouts and then choose one of them.
For example:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String language = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        adb.setView(inflater.inflate(language.equalsIgnoreCase("English") ?
                           R.layout.white_dialog : R.layout.blackdialog, null));
        adb.show();
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is no solution for my problem.